# Freezing when using gdb via TRAMP with gdb-many-windows enabled

Tags: tramp, gdb

The problem may be because I am doing this via Tramp, connecting to an Amazon ec2 instance where gdb is installed.

I had Emacs 28.2, and now I've upgraded to 29.1 and the same problem occurs. If I have gdb-many-windows on, and I start a debugging session, after a few steps, it freezes, and I observe a spike in Emacs' CPU usage. If I turn off gdb-many-windows, it works fine.

I'm on a 2021 MacBook Pro, M1 Pro Chip, 16GB, running macOS Ventura 13.4.1 (c).

When I issue `M-x gdb` to start, Emacs offers to run gdb with `-i=mi`. I tried opening with that setting and without it; without it, nothing even gets off the ground; it just fails right away.

Thanks for any help you can provide!